# pgAdmin4 disable master password

Tags: pgadmin

When starting pgAdmin, I'm prompted:

> Please set a master password for pgAdmin

This is a new feature of pgAdmin4 4.7: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/release_notes_4_7.html

How can I disable this?

The local documentation tells me to set the "configuration parameter" `MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False`, but I don't know where/how to do this: 
http://127.0.0.1:37059/help/help/master_password.html

Answer (score 30):

Took me a while to find out, that's why I'm posting it here:

1. You need to locate a file named `config.py`. In my case it's at `/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/config.py`
2. Now create a file `config_local.py` (in the same folder) and enter: `MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False`
3. Restart pgAdmin server.
4. The prompt should be gone :-)

Some reference about config files: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/desktop_deployment.html#configuration

**EDIT**: It looks like in higher versions (I now have pgAdmin4 4.26) the directory changed to `/usr/pgadmin4/web/`

Comment: For anyone that needs to do this on a machine on which they don't have root access, I would like to add that you could put this file in for example `~/.config/pgadmin` and then add this directory to the Python path setting in `~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf`, something like `PythonPath=/home/«username»/.config/pgadmin:/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Comment: Works on Windows too.

Comment: Does anyone know which directory this should be in on Windows?

Comment: Same here, I can't find it on Windows, I went in Program Files, AppData and Registry editor. Nada

Comment: If you download the macOS App Bundle, go to pgAdmin 4 in your Applications folder, and right click to select Show Package Contents. `config.py` should be in `Contents/Resources/web/`. Find the line with `MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=True`, and change it to `False`.

Comment: Maybe it's important to set `ALLOW_SAVE_PASSWORD = False` too? The documentation [explains](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/master_password.html) why it's not a very good idea to save passwords without a master password set.

Comment: Thanks, on Ubuntu 22.04, create a file at this location /usr/pgadmin4/web/config_local.py and set  MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED=False then restart pgadmin4.

Answer (score 11):

For those on windows, the `config.py` is located under

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\web
```

Create `config_local.py` inside of that folder

Comment: If you're on Windows, this is where the file is located now.  Don't waste your time looking in the AppData folder as other answers to this problem suggest.  If you have Postgres 14 , then the updated location would be  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web`